# Permission denied issue in cocos2d update

Tags: installation, permissions, xcode, ios

I have been trying to update to Cocos2D version 2, but I always get the following lines of code in the terminal.

```
Installing Xcode 4 Box2d iOS template
-------------------------------------------------

mkdir: /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x: Permission denied   ...copying Box2d files
rsync: mkdir "/Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x/lib_box2d.xctemplate/libs" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(544) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
rsync: mkdir "/Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x/lib_box2d.xctemplate/libs" failed: No such file or directory (2)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/main.c(544) [receiver=2.6.9]
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (8 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-42/rsync/io.c(452) [sender=2.6.9]
done!

Installing Xcode 4 CCNode file templates...
----------------------------------------------------

...creating destination directory: /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File   Templates/cocos2d v2.x/
mkdir: /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/cocos2d v2.x: Permission denied
mv: rename /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d v2.x//CCNode    class.xctemplate to /Users/jubilate/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/cocos2d v2.x/:   No such file or directory
done!
```

I installed using the command

```
./install-templates.sh -u -f
```

And also deleted folders beginning with "cocos2d" (previous version) in:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/cocos2d*
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/Templates/File Templates/cocos2d*
```

Could someone please assist me?

I have been at it for days.